# Chrome Extension Request Action Name Conflict

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using below code as my content script.

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action == 'main_request') {}
});
```

But if another extension uses same action name, may the request conflict with the other extension listener? Does action name need to be unique?

Answer (score 1):

`chrome.extension.onRequest` is deprecated, don't use it.
Use [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage).

As per the documentation for both functions:

> Sends a single message to event listeners within your extension/app or a different extension/app.

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest(extensionId, request, responseCallback)
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionId, message, options, responseCallback)
```

**The first parameter `extensionId` is optional, so when it's omitted the message is sent only within the extension.**

N.B. Optional parameters in Chrome API may be omitted regardless of the position in argument list.